# Load cell circuit does not work on circuit simulator

Tags: instrumentation-amplifier, multisim, load-cell, wheatstone-bridge, strain-gage

I want to simulate a load cell interfacing with AD620 for amplification.
- My load cell is 40 Kg max with 2mV/V sensitivity and 10 V excitation voltage with input resistance of 405 ohm and output resistance of 350 ohm as you can see.
I want an output voltage ranging from 0 to 2.5 V. Using AD620 gain equation from its datasheet, I calculated Rg to be 398 ohm, I have then used a 400 ohm resistor on the simulator.
First, my question is by how much should I vary R4 (strain resistor) to simulate the change in the real load cell because I am going to implement this circuit.
Second, is the circuit down here correct?
Regards,
[image]

Comment: If it doesn't work on a sim then you need to investigate this - the schematic looks ok to me.

Comment: You probably need to ground-reference your bridge to give the in-amp's input biasing currents somewhere to go. No real-world in-amp will work with a completely isolated differential input like that.

Comment: Thanks for it, it has solve the issue. How can I know how many strain gauges  does my load cell have? 1, 2 or 4?